# $Z(G)$ acts on set of conjugacy classes by left multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $z\in Z(G)$ then one can say that $(zx)^g=zx^g$. But it means that multiplication by $z$ create a bijection from conjugacy classes of $x$ to conjugacy classes of $xz$.

Let $\omega=\{C_1,C_2...,C_k\}$ be conjugacy classes of $G$ except the elements of $Z(G)$ then $Z(G)$ acts on $\omega$ by left multiplication.

I wonder that is there any good result based on this action ? Can we compute kernel of action or orbits of action expicitly ?

Comment: The kernel is clearly trivial (look at the action on the conjugacy class containing the identity).

Comment: For the orbits I'd try to look at the conjugacy classes of $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: More generally, if $z\in Z(G)$ fixes some conjugacy class, then at least the order of $z$ must divide the common order of the elements of that conjugacy class.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: The conjugacy class of a central element is its singleton.

Comment: @j.p. I know, and hence if it is fixed by the action, then the acting element is the identity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Ishould extract the elemets of $Z(G)$ from the conjugacy classes :)

Comment: Note that the kernel of action on the non-singleton conjugacy classes is still trivial due to my above comment on orders.

Comment: @mesel: Instead of "extracting" you should factor out the center.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: The oreder of elemets in conjugacy classes is already same. I did not understand what you mean exactly. If $|Z(G)|=p$ and $G$ is a $p$ group then $p$ divides every non trivial  conjugacy classes.

Comment: @j.p.: One can also think the induced action of $Z(G)$ on $G/Z(G)$ but I did not see the advantage of this action ?

Comment: Ohh, good point. So if the action does not have trivial kernel, then the group is a $p$-group with center of order $p$. Now to see if there is some small nice example with non-trivial kernel.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: What if  $G=P\times Q$ with $Z(G)=H\times K$ where $|H|=p$ and $|K|=q$ ?

Comment: @mesel: The induced action would be trivial. The preimages of the conjugacy classes of $G/Z(G)$ are the orbits. On each orbit $Z(G)$ acts regularly. I guess there is nothing interesting to gain here. Sorry.

Comment: @j.p.: We are making brain storm. it  is ok.

Comment: @mesel: The sorry referred to your question. I don't expect any interesting answer.